# How to add a button on left border of a cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to acheive the following (taken from dropbox):

[image]

My snippet (in full page):

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem !important

}

tr.red th {
  background: #FFF;
}
th {
    padding: 50px;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 111px; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-top: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th></th>
      <th>
          <div>
              Free
          </div>
          <div>
              0 / month
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="pricing-plans__cta button button--primary">Sub</a>
      </th>
      <th>
          <div>
              Premium
          </div>
          <div>
              99,99€ / month
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="pricing-plans__cta button button--primary">Sub</a>
          </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%;">
              <span>
                  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 22px; height: 22px; margin-left: -11px;">
                      <button style="width: 22px; height: 22px; display: block; background: transparent;" aria-label="More info"></button>
                  </div>
              </span>
              <span style="margin-left: 15px; display: flex;">Storage</span>
          </div>

      </td>
      <td>2 Go</td>
      <td>15 To</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go...**

The easiest way to achieve this circle with the letter "i" inside is to use Font Awesome icon. Move the icon to the left by setting `margin-left: -25px;`. You have to set `z-index: 100;` (the value is not important, it could be 1) to push the icon in front of everything else. It's necessary to set `position: absolute;`, otherwise the z-index won't work. Also, set `background-color: white;` so that the line of the table isn't visible in the background of the icon (try to remove the background-color to see what I'm talking about).

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem !important;
}

tr.red th {
  background: #FFF;
}

th {
  padding: 50px;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 111px;
  height: 250px;
  /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
}

.fa-info-circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -7%;
  margin-left: -24%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/js/all.js' data-auto-replace-svg='nest'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table style='margin-top: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
    <thead>
      <tr class='red'>
        <th> <i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i> </th>
        <th>
          <div>
            Free
          </div>
          <div>
            0 / month
          </div>
          <a href='#' class='pricing-plans__cta button button--primary'>Sub</a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div>
            Premium
          </div>
          <div>
            99,99€ / month
          </div>
          <a href='#' class='pricing-plans__cta button button--primary'>Sub</a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style='display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%;'>
            <span>
                        <div style='display: inline-block; width: 22px; height: 22px; margin-left: -11px;'>
                            <button style='width: 22px; height: 22px; display: block; background: transparent;' aria-label='More info'></button>
                        </div>
                    </span>
            <span style='margin-left: 15px; display: flex;'>Storage</span>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td>2 Go</td>
        <td>15 To</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why do I need js ? How can I vertical align it ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You actually don't need JS. I removed the script for JS and link for CSS. I forgot to remove that.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by vertically aligning it?

Comment: I mean the info bubble should be vertically centered*

Comment: What if the height of the cell change ?

Comment: I updated my answer. The margins are now set in relative units. I changed the height of the cell so you can see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by setting the position attribute of the button to absolute and then use it to position according to its ancestor

Here is an [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to know more about this

Add this CSS code to your file and it will work

```css
button{
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `<span class="information">i</span>` into your 1st `td` and then added the CSS as below:

```css
/* ADDED */
td::first-child{
  position:relative;
}
.information{
  position:absolute;
  left: -12px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem !important

}

tr.red th {
  background: #FFF;
}
th {
    padding: 50px;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 111px; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
}


/* ADDED */
td::first-child{
  position:relative;
}
.information{
  position:absolute;
  left: -12px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-top: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th></th>
      <th>
          <div>
              Free
          </div>
          <div>
              0 / month
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="pricing-plans__cta button button--primary">Sub</a>
      </th>
      <th>
          <div>
              Premium
          </div>
          <div>
              99,99€ / month
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="pricing-plans__cta button button--primary">Sub</a>
          </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <span class="information">i</span>
          <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%;">
              <span>
                  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 22px; height: 22px; margin-left: -11px;">
                      <button style="width: 22px; height: 22px; display: block; background: transparent;" aria-label="More info"></button>
                  </div>
              </span>
              <span style="margin-left: 15px; display: flex;">Storage</span>
          </div>

      </td>
      <td>2 Go</td>
      <td>15 To</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This will work for u

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

td a {
  font-family: initial;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
  left: -5%;
  top: 38%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
}

table {
  margin: 50px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#/">i</a> Espace de stockage</td>
    <td>2 Go</td>
    <td>2 To (2000 go)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#/">i</a> Espace de stockage</td>
    <td>2 Go</td>
    <td>2 To (2000 go)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#/">i</a> Espace de stockage</td>
    <td>2 Go</td>
    <td>2 To (2000 go)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The info bubble isn't vertically centered

Comment: @executable edited again just remember the font-size of `td` should be equal to the dimension of `info` button so as to align it vertically

Comment: I mean to the table cell

Comment: @executable i edited again see if it works

Comment: hmm is `top: 38%;` responsive ?

Comment: @executable yeah

Comment: I tried but all bubbles goes on the same position

Comment: @executable what does that mean were they stacking on one another

Comment: Yes they stack all together

Comment: @executable yes for that you can see that id assign position:relative to td which is parent to icon button.

Comment: @executable were you able to solve the problem ?